# Codeigniter 4 cookies issue not able to set

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

This is my controller code.  I am not able to set and get the cookies in Codeigniter 4.

```
helper('cookie');
$this->response->set_cookie('forgetpwd',$token, time() + (3600),"/",site_url());
print_r($this->request->get_cookie('forgetpwd'));
die();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `die()` because then the cookie will not be set. Let the method return instead so CI can output cookies and headers.

You do not need the helper, don't load it.

`site_url()` does not produce the string you should be using. It includes the protocol, i.e. `https://example.com` when all you should use is 'example.com'.

You have the *domain* and *path* arguments reversed and as others have said the call is to `setCookie()` as in

```
$this->response->setCookie('forgetpwd', $token, 3600, example.com);
```

The *expire* argument can be the life (in seconds) you want. The `setCookie()` method will add `time()` to it for you.

I don't supply a path argument because you need the default value of '/'.

Comment: this work for me without involving the domain  set_cookie('forgetpwd', $token,'3600'); thanks for your effort on the issue

Answer (score 1):

From php.net - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that
>   the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully
>   set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie
>   expires. Expire time is set via the expires parameter. A nice way to
>   debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling
>   print_r($_COOKIE);.

Comment: Good catch! Both our answers apply! :)

Comment: Thanks Tim You Are right .But i try to access the cookie on another page which is opened by clicking a link that i send on email with token to reset pwd page .the same token i want to set in cookie but it will not setting here at above code .

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. I get the cookie from the request and set it in the response. (Remember to validate the user input before processing it)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;  
use Config\Services;

class Home extends BaseController {

    public function setLang($lang = ""){
        // remember filter your inputs
        Services::response()->setCookie('lang', $lang);
        echo("<script>location='/index';</script>");
    }

    public function index(){
        //default value
        $lang = "es";
        //if empty return NULL.
        $tmpLang = Services::request()->getCookie("lang");
        if(in_array($tmpLang, ["es", "en", "ja", "pt"])){
            $lang = $tmpLang;
        }
        //show cookie value
        echo $lang
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using to redirect with cookies like

```
helper('cookie');    
set_cookie('cookie_name', 'value', 14400);    
return redirect()->to('url')->withCookies();
```

and on the page try getting by this way

```
print_r(get_cookie('cookie_name'));
```